# Gson don't ignore null field only for specific field(s)

Tags: java, json, gson

The [Gson guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Null-Object-Support) shows how to allow nulls, but it doesn't show how to allow null for some of the fields. I want some of the fields to be serialized as shown in the link and other null fields to be ignored.

Comment: Assuming you're looking for a solution where you can mark some fields as nullable or ignorable, Gson has no fine-grained such support. Use a custom `TypeAdapter`.